# Matrix multiplication with using einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I want to multiply two arrays with following dimensions:
A = (10, 1), B = (1, 1, 10, 18) using einsum.

```
tmp = np.einsum('pi,klpy ->kliy', A, B)
```

Do I need to switch dimensions of the B array to obtain correct results? 
I mean:

```
tmp = np.einsum('pi,lkyp ->kliy', A, B)
```

Comment: pretty sure the second won't even work

Comment: what is correct depends, really. do your axes represent anything specific? or could you write as a loop which operation you want implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware both results have different shapes?
If so you should most probably know what shape you'd expect.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.arange(10).reshape(1,10)
B=np.arange(180).reshape(1,1,10,18)

np.einsum('pi,klpy ->kliy', A, B).shape
np.einsum('pi,lkyp ->kliy', A, B).shape
```

**Results**

```
np.einsum('pi,klpy ->kliy', A, B).shape
Out: (1, 1, 10, 18)    
np.einsum('pi,lkyp ->kliy', A, B).shape
Out: (1, 1, 10, 10)
```